# Create Menu Separator for InkToolbar in Windows UWP

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

My Question is quite simple: I want to add a Separator to an InkToolbar like in the Windows Ink Sketchpad: 
[image: https://i.imgur.com/GTow5d4.png]

---

I have already tried it with `<AppBarSeparator/>`
but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: You should add the code you wrote and the errors you got (if any) in order to see what the problem is.

Comment: Actually there is no Problem, I just want to know how to add a Separator to an InkToolbar because I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't directly add a separator to InkToolBar,AppBarSeparator is generally used in the AppBar or CommandBar.You can try to add a CustomToolButton to InkToolBar.Then set the line image to it and disable it.If you still want to use AppBarSeparator,you can set a commandbar and put InkToolBar in it.

Use InkToolbarCustomToolButton:

```
<InkToolbar x:Name="toolbar" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}">
            <InkToolbarCustomToolButton Name="lassoSelectionButton" IsEnabled="False">
                <Image Source="Assets/vertical_line.png"></Image>
            </InkToolbarCustomToolButton>
            <InkToolbarCustomToggleButton Name="mouseInkingButton">
            </InkToolbarCustomToggleButton>
            ......
</InkToolbar>
```

Use CommandBar:

```
<CommandBar Width="300">
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <InkToolbar x:Name="toolbar" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}">
                </InkToolbar>
            </CommandBar.Content>
            <AppBarSeparator /> 
            ......
</CommandBar>
```